# CSS different resolutions

Tags: css, resolution

On different resolutions the search input just moves a bit top and left, and I can't fix it.

```
<div id="container" style="margin:0 auto; max-height:100%; ">
    <nav id="nav" style="margin:0 auto; background-color:#2d3e46; position:fixed; width:100%; height:77px; overflow:hidden;">
        <div class="logo" style="background-image:url('images/arti.png'); width:68px; height:40px; margin-top:1.1%; margin-left:6%;"></div>
        <form method="POST" style="margin-top:-2.4%">
            <input type="text" class="search" style="position:relative; background-color:white;width:207px; height:30px; border-radius:2px; text-indent:4px; margin-left:25%;" />
            <br />
        </form>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.logo` element has a % based margin so it will always change on different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

As Joseph stated
Some of the elements have % based margin, and as a results these will move when viewed on different resolutions, try to give them a fixed margin, fx, 10px.